# JQGrid inserted new row id is undefined?

Tags: c#, asp.net, jqgrid, row, addition

I'm using the following code for insert new row to my JQGrid :

```
var newRow = [{ ID: memberId, FullName: memberFullName, Percent: parseInt(percent), DelText: deleteString}];
grid.addRowData(memberId, newRow);
```

The code works well and new row is added to the jqgrid, but the `id` of the row is `undefined` and I can't select the new rows at all.
What's wrong and how can I fix it ? 
you can see the id of the row in below image(firebug)

[image: JQGrid grid in firebug]

Comment: yes, it's defined ,I was tested it with some random data, but the error occurred again !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've found the solution :
I had to write the code as the following :

```
var newRow = [{ ID: memberId, FullName: memberFullName, Percent: parseInt(percent), DelText: deleteString}];
grid.addRowData("ID", newRow);
```

Comment: Thank you.
saved me from wasting entire day.